# Splitting organic and paid impressions in facebook api using R

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rfacebook

I am using the Rfacebook package to retreive total impressions a facebookpost had. This works fine, however, this method does not split paid and organic impressions. I use the following code:

```
getInsights(object_id="post_id", token= token, metric='post_impressions')
```

Does anyone know how I can differentiate between organic and paid impressions/reach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [Facebook Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights) section on **Page Post Impressions**.

You should be able to pass values for `metric` as

- `'post_impressions_paid'`
- `'post_impressions_fan_paid'`
- `'post_impressions_organic'`
- `'post_impressions_viral'`
- `'post_impressions_nonviral'`
- etc...

to retrieve the various measures you need.

`metric` can also be a character vector which will allow you to retrieve many at once.

Comment: This is not an option in the Rfacebook package. How would I go around it and use the facebook api direct (in R)?

Comment: @nemja why would that not be an option? Looking at the docs, `metric` seems to be a normal string parameter, that you can pass any value you like for ...

Comment: You may also need to pass a newer version than 2.3. Try adding the parameter `version=2.12`. If this still doesn't run you would need to formulate the GET request yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ruaridhw!